# Tank auth Register always expired

Tags: php, codeigniter

can everybody help me..

I want use captcha in my registration form.
I use Codeigniter 2.0 with tank auth, but the captcha always expired when I resgister.

This config for captcha tank auth:

```
$config['captcha_path'] = 'captcha/';
$config['captcha_fonts_path'] = 'captcha/fonts/1.ttf';
$config['captcha_width'] = 200;
$config['captcha_height'] = 50;
$config['captcha_font_size'] = 18;
$config['captcha_grid'] = FALSE;
$config['captcha_expire'] = 180;
$config['captcha_case_sensitive'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Do the captcha images display?

Comment: The captcha displayed...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
$config['captcha_path'] = 'captcha/';
```

change to this:

```
$config['captcha_path'] = './PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGES_FOLDER/captcha/';
```

You have to make sure that you have a folder named captcha in your images folder of course with proper permissions.

If captcha displayed then try to re-uploaded dx_auth.php in the config folder.

Also please check config.php are you using ‘local’ or ‘gmt’ for your time_reference?

Either way, try switching it from one to the other and try the captcha again.  It seems to be an issue of the timezone differences and the cookies expiring.

Comment: The folder have true, Captcha has displayed

Comment: not yet shuvo... After I submit the form, I get "Your confirmation code has expired. Please try again."

Comment: if you have any javascript problem on your page this will end your captcha session so solve any javascript errors , and reinstall dx_auth on your server ( upload auth controller again and other files )

Comment: yes, you're right shuvo. This javascript code that makes an error.

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#krj").load('<?php echo base_url();?>cart/krj');
})</script>

how can I still use jquery load event?

Comment: How did you find that it is javascript which is causing the problem? I am also getting the same error.